# Converting Matlab code to python finding indices

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, indexing

I am new to Python and I am trying to convert the below matlab code to python. However, I am finding it tricky to get the same data.

The matlab code is below:

```
for j=1:D(1)
    [~,indx]=find(D==j);
    if ~isempty(indx)
        if find(diff(indx)>1)
            indx=indx(1:find(diff(indx)>1));
        end
        t(j)=(time(indx(1))+time(indx(end)))/2;
    else
        t(j)=NaN;
    end
end
```

Where D and time are row vectors of equal lengths.

`D = [32  31  31  31  30  30  30  29  28  29  28  28  28]`

`time = linspace(0,0.024,13)`

I have tried replicating the code in Python but I am stuck on the second if statement.

```
D = np.array([32,   31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 28, 29, 28, 28, 28])
time = np.linspace(0,0.024,13)

pixel = np.linspace(1, D[0], num=D[0], dtype=float)
t=[]
for j in range(len(pixel)):
    [indx] = (np.where(D == j+1))
    if not len(indx)==0:
       if np.where(np.diff(indx) > 1):
            indx = indx[0:np.where(np.diff(indx) > 1)]
       tt = (time[indx[0]] + time[indx[-1]]) /2
       t.append(tt)
    else:
        tt = np.nan
        t.append(tt)
t = np.asarray(t)
```

`np.where(np.diff(indx) > 1)` produces a np array, which I am assuming is the issue when indexing `indx`.

Any help would be great!

Comment: the variable `D[0]` is used before it is defined. So what is `D` please ?  Also, presume that you use `numpy as np` and `import time`...

Comment: `D` is a NumPy array , equivalent to `D` in the Matlab code.`D[0]` is the first value of `D`. Yes sorry, numpy as np. `time` is another NumPy array of the same length as `D`.

Comment: You might wish to quickly edit the question, so that the problem is reproducible by others. (it will also help you):   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A different approach to this question might be to provide the input / output from Matlab, and ask how it can be achieved in Python.  (Rather than us trying to interpret the ML code, with unknown data).